# Как вывести элемент ответа json на python

Tags: python, json, requests

Только начал работать с реквестами на питоне.

Никак не могу понять как вывести элемент.

Есть приходящий запрос:

```
{
  "id": 11631253,
  "created_at": "2018-10-13T08:13:38.809469028Z",
  "phone": "+79000381454",
  "product": "vkontakte",
  "price": 21,
  "status": "RECEIVED",
  "expires": "2018-10-13T08:28:38.809469028Z",
  "sms": [
      {
        "created_at":"2018-10-13T08:20:38.809469028Z",
        "date":"2018-10-13T08:19:38Z",
        "sender":"VKcom",
        "text":"VK: 09363 - use this code to reclaim your suspended profile.",
        "code":"09363"
      }
  ],
  "forwarding": false,
  "forwarding_number": "",
  "country":"russia"
}
```

Мне нужно вывести поле sms - code. Но я смог вывести только поле sms.

Таким образом:

```
response = requests.get('$DOMAIN' + num_id, headers=headers)
        result = json.loads(response.text)
        ph_sms = (result['sms'])
```

Вопрос, можно ли как то это сделать и как.

Буду очень признателен, если подскажите как это сделать!

Comment: Внутри sms находится массив с одним элементом, значит `result['sms'][0]`. Этот элемент это словарь, в котором есть ключ code, значит `result['sms'][0]['code']`

Comment: Ну и requests тут естественно ни при чём, работа с массивами и словарями это самые базовые основы питона

Comment: @andreymal Выдает ошибку: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Значит перед выполнением этого кода проверяйте что массив `result['sms']` не пустой

Comment: @andreymal Все понял, разобрался спасибо